# ActiveRecord NoMethodError: undefined method `association' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

With Rails 5.1.4, after changing a `#find` to preload a `has_many` association using `#includes`:

```
Website.includes(:configured_checks).find(params[:id])
```

An exception was thrown:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `association' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 4):

## `id` and `x_id` need to have the same type

This issue exposed a bug from renaming the owner of a `has_many` relation. When the table was renamed the type of the `t.belongs_to` column on the association no longer matched the table it referenced, causing the `NoMethodError: undefined method 'association' for nil:NilClass`.

Incorrect schema:

```
# Website id here is a UUID:
create_table "websites", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
end

# The foreign_key became a binint rather than uuid:
create_table "configured_checks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "website_id"
end
```

Corrected schema after a migration:

```
# Website id here is a UUID:
create_table "websites", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
end

# The website_id is now a uuid:
create_table "configured_checks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.uuid "website_id"
end
```